# onscreen reference doesn't open

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am using IE 10 on a new computer and when I try to open the Onscreen Reference for Intuit Development Kits, I get a message that BackBase software does not support the browser.  After downloading the latest Firefox, I am able to open the OSR, but it acts strangely.  What can I do to get IE 10 to open the OSR or to get Firefox to work properly?

Answer (score 2):

Enable compatibility mode and see if that resolves the issue.